# Sylow subgroup of $G$ with order the smallest prime factor of $|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

**Problem:** Let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing the order of the finite group $G$. If $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and
$P$ is cyclic prove that $N_G(P) = C_G(P)$.

I know the **standard proof** constructing an injection $\pi:N_G(P)/C_G(P)\to Aut(P)$ and calculating the order of $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$. But I remember my teacher could prove it using neither $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$ nor the injection $\pi$. Instead he proved it by constructing **several** (not only one, as I can vaguely remember) group actions and calculating orbits, which is quite impressive to me at that time. But I cannot remember his method now. Can anyone help reproduce it?

Comment: As you said, the usual proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554316/if-p-in-syl-pg-and-p-is-cyclic-then-n-gp-c-gp?rq=1). One may avoid the quotient though, but it wold amount to a similar argument nevertheless, I think, just in a different terminology. I am not sure that it would be helpful, since the above proof is already short and elegant.